# Erro to find module when converting ES6 function export to CommonJS

Tags: node.js, commonjs

Trying to replicate a [push notification project](https://felixgerschau.com/web-push-notifications-tutorial/#project-setup) I came cross with this function

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

export default async () => {
  // Connect to the database
  try {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/web-push-notifications', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Couldn't connect to the database: ${e}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
```

I convert in this way:

**database.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const connection =  async () => {
  // Connect to the database
  try {
    await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/web-push-notifications', {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });

    mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(`Couldn't connect to the database: ${e}`);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};

module.exports = {connection:connection}
```

I call that in `server.js`

```
const database = require("database")

database.connection();
```

I receive an error: `Cannot find module 'database'`

Where Am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the ./ In require, or wherever database.js is in relation to where you're requiring it.

Comment: True, Thanks Phix!